# How debug A data monitoring website for PLC

Tags: python, flask, web, plc

I'm currently working on a project myself. We are trying to make Mitsubishi PLC data accessible over the internet. Can you guide me through the steps

I want to set up a website using Python/Flask and install the Pymodbus extension to proceed from here. How can I continue? If you have any other suggestions that might be easier, I'm open to recommendations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all in order to secure your installation, let's **not** grant direct access to your website to all the internet. Whats I would do :

1. Host a python website server somewhere
2. Run locally (on your hardware installation, whatever it is) a script to send data ([request.post](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp)) to the website server. And then serve the aggregated data in a client web page. That way the data are accessible from anywhere in the world, but without opening access to the hardware itself...

If you want to give it a try easily I would advice to use [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) which is an easy way to setup (for free) a Python Env and play with it